# In Deuteronomy 32:40, does The Lord of Israel claim to dwell below the highest heaven?

Tags: deuteronomy, authorial-intent, context, heaven

In Deuteronomy 32:40, why would The Lord say "I lift My Hand to heaven" - **Does The Lord of Israel claim to dwell below the highest heaven?**

---

NIV | **Deuteronomy 32:40-41**

"**40 I lift My Hand to heaven and solemnly swear: As surely as I live forever,**

41 when I sharpen my flashing sword and my hand grasps it in judgment, I will take vengeance on my adversaries and repay those who hate me."

---

- Is there another heaven above the heaven in which The Lord of Israel judges us? (Multiple heavens are referenced by The Lord in Deuteronomy 32:1 "Listen, you heavens")

Answer (score 3):

Jehovah spoke with Moses face to face, by a similitude (a likeness) as a man speaks to his friend. And it was there that Jehovah communicated this song.

> With him will I speak mouth to mouth, even apparently, and not in dark speeches; and the similitude of the LORD shall he behold: wherefore then were ye not afraid to speak against my servant Moses? [Numbers 12:8 KJV]

From that vantage point, the Lord speaking to Moses, within the tabernacle, heaven is above and, within the framework of that conversation, Jehovah would express the lifting of a hand to heaven as a form of oath.

> For I lift up to the heavens my hand [Deuteronomy 32:40 YLT]

The similitude which Moses saw, and with which Moses conversed, as a man speaks to his friend, was on earth - not in heaven.

Therefore heaven was above the speaking similitude.

Answer (score 2):

The passage in context:

> <sup>39</sup> “‘See now that I, even I, am he,
> and there is no god beside me;
> I kill and I make alive;
> I wound and I heal;
> and there is none that can deliver out of my hand.
> <sup>40</sup> For I lift up my hand to heaven
> and swear, As I live forever (Deuteronomy 32:39-40) [ESV]

The previous verse begins with a statement from the LORD that He is "I Am." In this instance literally "I, I Am" (אֲנִי אֲנִי הוּא *’ănî ’ănî hū'*). When "I Am" is recognized as Jesus, the passage may be paraphrased:

> I, I am (Father and Son) and there is no god beside me. I kill and make alive; I wound and I heal; and there is none that can deliver out of my hand. For I [Jesus] lift up My hand to heaven and swear, as I live forever.

Moses is speaking prophetically. When I Am is on the earth He will be lifted up to heaven.

Comment: Although this is an interpretation, I still think it is valid and was in my mind when I composed my own answer. (Up-voted +1.)

Answer (score 1):

1 Kings 8:27

> "But will God really **dwell** on earth? The heavens, even the **highest heaven**, cannot contain you. How much less this temple I have built!

In Deuteronomy 32:40, does The Lord of Israel claim to dwell below the highest heaven?

No.